# xparse/command-already-defined

Tags: incompatibility, xparse

Hello I am trying to use the following class (yReport.cls) from this link https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX

I am using MikTex 2.9 and I have installed the relevant packages, fonts and cls files. Unfortunately the following error comes and I do not know how to fix it:

```
! LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined"
! 
! Command '\FA' already defined!
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
```

This error comes up when loading the following code which is the minimal amount of code required for the layout to work:

```
\documentclass[french]{yReport}

\author{Your name}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\title{Title}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfsubject={Subject},
    pdfauthor={Your name},
    pdfkeywords={{keyword 1}{keyword 2}},
}

\makeatletter
\let\runauthor\@author
\let\runtitle\@title
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \titleTwo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal (non) working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Added a not working example

Comment: There is no problem when rendering using XeLaTeX or pdfTeX. The word Lorem appears as it should

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[marginIcons]{infoBulle}\usepackage{fontawesome}\begin{document}Lorem\end{document}`?

Comment: That does not work, the same error message comes up

Comment: Good. I suspect `infoBulle` defines things that `fontawesome` defines, so the definitions clash.

Comment: How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: I'd say `infoBulle` is broken. It does `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` when it should not since that is for `fontawesome` to do. Complain to the author. The cheap fix would be to edit `infoBulle.sty` and remove the line `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` (https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/blob/12bad7f7cdd88193c6c221160d1b5ec50f43878c/yPackages/infoBulle/infoBulle.sty#L115). In fact what `infoBulle` does is really weird. First it loads `fontawesome` and then sixty odd lines later it does `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}`, I really don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be reproduced with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{infoBulle}
\begin{document}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

You'll need `infoBulle.sty` from https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/tree/master/yPackages/infoBulle and `yMainColor.sty` from https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/blob/master/yPackages/yMainColor/ to run the code.

A short investigation reveals that `infoBulle.sty` not only loads the `fontawesome` package (in [line 44](https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/blob/12bad7f7cdd88193c6c221160d1b5ec50f43878c/yPackages/infoBulle/infoBulle.sty#L44)), but it also issues

```
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
```

later on in [line 115](https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/blob/12bad7f7cdd88193c6c221160d1b5ec50f43878c/yPackages/infoBulle/infoBulle.sty#L115).

At that point, however, `fontawesome` has executed that same line itself and we get an error.

It seems to me that `infoBulle.sty` is wrong in using `\FA` with `\newfontfamily` for FontAwesome when `fontawesome` is already loaded. This should be reported to the `infoBulle` maintainer (https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/issues/8). The maintainer has responded quickly and a fixed version is available on GitHub.

In the meantime the easiest, but also dirtiest, fix is to edit your local copy of `infoBulle.sty` and to remove (or comment out) the `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` in line 115.

[sab hoque](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/166730/sab-hoque)'s investigations show that the problem did not occur with older versions of `fontspec`. And indeed the `fontspec` documentation explains

> [`\newfontfamily`, `\setfontfamily`, `\renewfontfamily`] These commands define new font family commands (like `\rmfamily`). The `new` command checks if `⟨cmd⟩` has been defined, and issues an error if so. The `renew` command checks if `⟨cmd⟩` has been defined, and issues an error if not. The `set` command never checks; use at your own risk.
>
> **NEW**: In previous versions of `fontspec`, only `\newfontfamily` was provided, but it behaved like `\setfontfamily`. You’ll have to update your code slightly if this now causes problems; apologies.

So in older versions of `fontspec` the `\newfontfamily` in `infoBulle` would simply overwrite the default in `fontawesome`, but now the two `\newfontfamily`s with the same name clash and generate an error.

Comment: I found out the problem. So essentially in earlier editions of fontec, `\newfontfamily` worked fine but in the current version it has to be replaced with `setfontfamily`. Your answer unfortunately is unable to render anything while using the infoBulle package but changing it to `setfontfamily` makes everything work fine. Thanks for the help

Comment: @moewe You are absolutely correct about the new command `\setfontfamily`. I changed the package code. Everything should now be working

Comment: This is very late but removing `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` from line 115 causes some other features to not work/render correctly, anyhow for any new viewers I would recommend downloading the new version from the appropriate github page

Comment: @sabhoque Mhhh, since the `fontawesome` package executes a similar line, removing it should not affect functionality that much. But I'm afraid that I can't say anything without a short MWE that reproduces a loss in functionality here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem resides in the newer version of fontec. I added the following line

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

at around line 43 or so. I also changed `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` to `\setfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` Now it works as it should. Also LuaLaTeX should be used instead of XeLaTeX

Comment: Do you mean `fontspec` instead of `fontenc`? `fontenc` should not be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: opps yes i meant fontspec