# Awesome-CV error(s)

Tags: xetex, cv, fontawesome, awesome-cv

I am trying to use the AwesomeCV template (https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) for creating a CV using TexMaker 5.0.3 with XeLaTex. However, I am not able to get this to work as I get the following error messages:

[image: Error messages I get when trying to compile with XeLaTex]

Does anyone know what the source of problem might be and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Cheers

Comment: Helps in this case to know platform but presume its Texmaker on Windows and looking at issues windows users have the old comment is that since some example files are just links "After much hair pulling, the issue was fixed by replacing the files awesome-cv.cls and fontawesome.sty in the examples directory with the same named files in the parent directory."

Comment: Yes, I am running on Windows 10. I don't have an example directory: both awesome-cv.cls and fontawesome.sty are already in the parent directory.

Comment: OK on firing up Tm5 on 10 with MiKTeX using fresh download I get many errors as expected with generic templates but you don't say which document you are running so I run CV and see font heading issues similar with resume and coverletter however they all compile without your specific error simply a \FA error and many many warnings thus suggest the root of your problem is any mods you made and best raised at https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues

Comment: Just for others benefit "Command \FA already defined" is an open issue #234 and the proposed fix is to edit the .cls see https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/234 after that fix all works as expected with a few bad box warnings

Comment: P.S. perhaps should have asked if **all files** from both main and examples directory are available to each other since they are inter dependent thus expects a /fonts /cv and /resume subdirectory

Answer (score 6):

As requested I am adding a temporary answer.

This error

> Error: Command \FA already defined

It affects some calls to `fontawesome` either direct or in a similar fashion to those reported in [xparse/command-already-defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453188/xparse-command-already-defined/453198#453198)

The solution is to update all secondary calls of 
`\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` to be `\setfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}`.

Is a current  known open issue [#234 (2018/2019)](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/234) in awsome cv due to above need to change the `.cls` syntax and should have been closed by downloading the latest version. However the fix does not appear to have been Pull Requested or added to the master `.cls` file.

The working modified `awesome-cv.cls` from last year is [available here](https://github.com/ashwinvis/Awesome-CV/raw/97c094f2c469b42affe8bee7b8db0db7b782ba8a/awesome-cv.cls)

**Note at the same time you need to ensure the fonts are in the correct /fonts subfolder to the cv, resume and cover-letter!** that is in the folder with the tex files the fonts folder should be a sub folder /awsometex/fonts/fontfiles where awsometex is the folder with letter.tex etc and the fontfiles are those from the package.