# Awesome-CV tempplate giving an error while running

Tags: xetex, cv, fontawesome, awesome-cv

I am new to Latex. I really like the awesome CV template and would like to use it. However I am not able to make it work. I am running it using the XELatex. I am getting the following error and I am not able to solve it. I would appreciate if anyone could help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance,
Jon
[image]

Comment: Could you please add a minimal working example?

Comment: the MWE is the full class file since this looks like it is two issues One is a known fault in the .cls file the other is weak instructions for a new user as to how to apply fonts 1) get a valid .cls file 2) ensure you know how to position fonts so they are found relative to the tex files see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476473/170109

Comment: %!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% CONFIGURATIONS
%-------------------
% A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
% Configure page margins with geometry
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}
\fontdir[fonts/] 
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue} % Color for highlights
awesome color
\setbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{true}

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sectioncolor}{\color}{\mdseries\color}{}{}
\makeatother

Comment: This is part of the code